# problems with addGap(int) in GroupLayout.Group

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

This is the snippet :

```
JPanel logoPanel=new JPanel();
GroupLayout logoLayout=new GroupLayout(logoPanel);
logoPanel.setLayout(logoLayout);
logoPanel.setHorizontalGroup((GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addGap(100,100));
logoPanel.setVerticalGroup((GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addGap(100,100));
```

---

These are the errors produced on cmd :

```
MainPageTypo.java:27: cannot find symbol
logoPanel.setHorizontalGroup((GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addGap(100,100));
                                                            ^
symbol:   method addGap(int,int)
location: class Alignment
MainPageTypo.java:28: cannot find symbol
logoPanel.setVerticalGroup((GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addGap(100,100));
                                                          ^
symbol:   method addGap(int,int)
location: class Alignment
2 errors
```

Why it is giving these errors and how can i solve them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.Group.html) GroupLayout.Group only has methods `addGap(int)` and `addGap(int, int, int)` so you're either missing one parameter or have one too much.

`addGap(100)` should thus be sufficient.

Edit 2:

You're calling `addGap(...)` on `GroupLayout.Alignment` which is an enum and doesn't provide that method at all: line 28 contains `(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addGap(100,100)`

I think you want to call `logoLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)` or `logoLayout.createSequentialGroup()` to create a group.

You're also calling `setHorizontalGroup(...)` (and `setVerticalGroup(...)`) on the JPanel and not on the GroupLayout which should also generate errors. Change that to `logoLayout.setHorizontalGroup( ... );`.

Edit: a short hint on what the message means

```
symbol:   method addGap(int,int)   //the symbol that is searched for
location: class Alignment   //the symbol (method) is searched in class Alignment or its class hierarchy
MainPageTypo.java:28: cannot find symbol  //the compiler cant find the symbol stated above which is used at line 28 in file MainPageTypo.java 
logoPanel.setVerticalGroup((GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE).addGap(100,100)); // this is the content of line 28
```

Comment: @ Thomas Giving exceptions.. [complete code](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/MainPageTypo.java)

Comment: @Suhail Could you post the exceptions?

Comment: @Thomas +1 very well spot. @Suhail Gupta Please correct also other errors in the snippet.

Comment: @Suhail Please don't make us compile and run your code in order to spot exceptions. "There are exceptions" isn't very helpful as isn't "fine, now I get this exception". Please learn how to read and interpret exceptions as well as how to debug. When you get an exception, you should at least read the JavaDoc of the class/method you use and maybe just try to google the exception if the JavaDoc doesn't answer it. I bet the `IllegalStateException` you got is described in the JavaDoc - why it is thrown, how to fix it, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you also correct the code snippet to a correct form, which is in the code you provided.

From what I see you get:

```
IllegalStateException: Baseline must be used along vertical axis
```

It mean the first parallel group cannot be created on baseline change it e.g. to LEADING.
And it compiles.